# Discord.js trying to get nickname from message.mentions.users.first()

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to get the nickname of the first mentioned user and then get the length of the nickname.
I tried `message.mentions.users.first()` but i don't think this gets the nickname.
I am using discord.js on visual studios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`message.mentions.users.first()` returns the User object. However Users dont have a `nicknane` property, you need to get the Member object then add `.nickname.length` to it

```
message.mentions.members.first().nickname.length
```